# Apache camel : how to split the file and send to multiple end points

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am new to Apache Camel and using Java DSL. I want to send a image file to different end points by splitting it using image processing tool. What are all the components do I need to use to achieve that and also I need to send the split images to one more end point.

Comment: Will you be splitting the image outside of Camel?

Comment: I am planning to get that file using Exchange get In method and will be splitting it using external class which will return the image files                                                                    File inputFile = exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the chapter "Using a Pojo to do the splitting" from http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html

Example for your needs as far as i understood for the pojo:

```
public List<Message> splitMessage(Exhange exchange) {
    List<Message> answer = new ArrayList<Message>();
    File inputFile = exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);
    List<YourObject> parts = yourSplittingOfTheFile(inputFile);
    for (YourObject part : parts) {
        DefaultMessage message = new DefaultMessage();
        message.setBody(body);
        answer.add(message);
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Afterwards you can send each part to one or more endpoints in your split block.

kind regards,
soilworker